# Is it possible to access clipboard from js running inside CEF?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, chromium-embedded

I need to be able to view clipboard content from javascript running inside CEF. I know, that it is not possible in Chrome, due to security restrictions, and i can't use Flash, Silverlight etc. I just wandering maybe CEF has some configurable option for it.

Comment: Try the --disable-web-security flag in OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing.